# Nginx: one directory should be redirected below itself

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have been struggling with a simple problem with nginx redirecting, but to avail so far.

I have two (language based) domains:

```
server {
  server_name a.b.com;
  .
  .
  .
}

server {
  server_name d.b.com;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Now on d.b.com/example, should redirect to d.b.com/example/right. I have tried to build a location like below (plus a lot of variations of it including full urls).

```
location ^/example {
  redirect /example /example/right permanent;
}
```

Nginx allows the syntax, but when I try to open the page, I always get the 404.

I think this should be straight-forward but my brain just can't get it right, nor have I found the solution in the web.

The biggest problem is that the end users already sent the mass mailing to our customers with the invalid link (without even checking it!), so I am a bit hard pressed with timetable...

wbr

hank

Comment: Do you have a folder structure like the url described (/example/right/index.*) ? If not I suggest you put something like `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` in your `location ^/example` block and implement a router in your code.

Comment: You have set the redirect but when the redirect happens to `/example/right` is any other block handling it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to match a single URI, use an exact match `location`:

```
location = /example {
    return 301 /example/right;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for :)